# Getting maximum counts of a column in grouped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

My dataframe `df` is:

```
    Election Year   Votes   Party   Region
  0   2000           50      A       a
  1   2000           100     B       a
  2   2000           26      A       b
  3   2000           180     B       b
  4   2000           300     A       c
  5   2000           46      C       c
  6   2005           149     A       a
  7   2005           46      B       a
  8   2005           312     A       b
  9   2005           23      B       b
  10  2005           16      A       c
  11  2005           35      C       c
```

I want to get the Party winning maximum region every year. So the desired output is:

```
 Election Year Party
   2000         B
   2005         A
```

I tried this code to get the the above output, but it is giving error:

```
 winner = df.groupby(['Election Year'])['Votes'].max().reset_index()
 winner = winner.groupby('Election Year').first().reset_index()
 winner = winner[['Election Year', 'Party']].to_string(index=False)
 winner
```

how can I get the desired output?

Comment: Why does your expected output for 2000 list B as the party when A has the higher number of votes in that year (300)?

Comment: Because Party B is winning more regions in 2000. So in 2000, B is the winner. And for any region, winner is one who gets maximum votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach with nested groupby. We first count per-party votes in each year-region pair, then use `mode` to find the party winning most regions. The mode need not be unique (if two or more parties win the same number of regions).

```
df.groupby(["Year", "Region"])\
  .apply(lambda gp: gp.groupby("Party").Votes.sum().idxmax())\
  .unstack().mode(1).rename(columns={0: "Party"})
```

---

```
     Party
Year      
2000     B
2005     A
```

---

To address the comment, you can replace `idxmax` above with `nlargest` and `diff` to find regions where win margin is below a given number.

```
margin = df.groupby(["Year", "Region"])\
  .apply(lambda gp: gp.groupby("Party").Votes.sum().nlargest(2).diff()) > -125

print(margin[margin].reset_index()[["Year", "Region"]])

#    Year Region
# 0  2000      a
# 1  2005      a
# 2  2005      c
```

Comment: How to get replace '0'  by "Party"? Renaming the column "0" is not working. Everything else is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How to get the list of regions in which two largest party has vote difference less than 125?

Comment: @Dpknew See the new edit. Normally you would want to stick to one question per post.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`GroupBy.idxmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) to get the index of max `Votes` for each group of `Election Year`, then use `.loc` to locate the rows followed by selection of required columns, as followed:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('Election Year')['Votes'].idxmax()][['Election Year', 'Party']]
```

Result:

```
   Election Year Party
4           2000     A
8           2005     A
```

### Edit

If we are to get the `Party` winning most `Region`, we can use the following codes (without using the slow `.apply()` with lambda function):

```
(df.loc[
    df.groupby(['Election Year', 'Region'])['Votes'].idxmax()]
    [['Election Year', 'Party', 'Region']]
    .pivot(index='Election Year', columns='Region')
    .mode(axis=1)
).rename({0: 'Party'}, axis=1).reset_index()
```

Result:

```
   Election Year Party
0           2000     B
1           2005     A
```

Comment: Note that OP expects B to win most regions in year 2000.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
winner = df.groupby(['Election Year','Party'])['Votes'].max().reset_index()
winner.drop('Votes', axis = 1, inplace = True)
winner
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method: (closed to @hilberts_drinking_problem in fact)

```
>>> df.groupby(["Election Year", "Region"]) \
      .apply(lambda x: x.loc[x["Votes"].idxmax(), "Party"]) \
      .unstack().mode(axis="columns") \
      .rename(columns={0: "Party"}).reset_index()

   Election Year Party
0           2000     B
1           2005     A
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the one liner `df.groupby(["Election Year"]).max().reset_index()['Election Year', 'Party']` solves your problem